# Proving $a_1\cos t + a_2\cos 2t+\dots+a_n\cos nt=-1$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Given: $f(z)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+a_2z^{n-2}+...+a_{n-1}z^{1}+a_nz^{0}=0$,

$z=cist$, $a_n \in R$.

Need to prove:

$a_1\cos t + a_2\cos 2t+\dots+a_n\cos nt=-1$

So i see that:

$Re(f(z))=cos(nt)+a_1cos((n-1)t)+...+a_ncos((n-n)t)=0$

can i just put n=0 and using $cos(-x)=cos(x)$ to prove?

Because i can't see how to continue.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to start by dividing by $z^n$

Comment: Use $e^{it}$ notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** Divide the expression $f(z)=0$ throughout by $z^n.$ Use $z=\cos \theta + \sin \theta$ with De Moivre's theorem and take the real part.

Comment: That's what i did. as you can see i wrote what i got after that.

Comment: I made an edit.

Comment: why can u divided by $z^n$? what if z^n=0? it can be.

Comment: What do you understand by $z=\cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ ? What is $|z|$ ?